# AWS 'Amplify push' command giving 'file already exists in amplify/.temp/#current-cloud-backend' error in React Native project

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, github, aws-amplify

I created a new React Native project and initialized a new AWS Amplify project inside this folder and added just 1 category(Add Auth). However, when i do a 'Amplify push' i get following error:

"There was an error pulling the backend environment 'dev', an error occurred during the push operation. EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir '..projectDirectory/amplify/.temp/#current-cloud-backend'"

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you try deleting ```..projectDirectory/amplify/.temp/``` and running ```amplify push```?

Comment: Hi yudhiesh, if i delete the .temp folder, it gets created again when i run 'amplify push'. then i get the same error again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify that your current node version satisfies the aws amplify requirements (>= 10.12).

Comment: Hi jbg, thank you so much, my issue is resolved! I upgraded my node version and the 'Amplify push' was successful :)